# Splitting a string with delimiters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

I have a field that contains values like:

xxx-xxxx-xx-xx

xxxx-xx-xxxx-x

In excel, if I used the "text to columns" feature (with the "-" as a delimiter),  I would end up with:

xxx  xxxx xx   xx

xxxx xx   xxxx x

I am trying to accomplish the same effect in Sql Server 2008 using sting functions like `charindex` etc but just can't seem to get the hang of it.

Thanks in advance for your help.
John

Comment: This kind of topic has been covered by a multitude of previous questions and blog articles, Aaron Bertrands is a very good one to read : http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings